# Is a constant as a function continuously differentiable?

Tags: functions

Well, it may seem trivial, but I cannot find it on google. Is a constant function continuously differentiable, of all orders?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. $f'$ and all higher derivatives are identically equal to zero.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume this is a constant function on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = c$ for some fixed $c$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Fix any $x_0$. What is

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \ \ ?
$$

In particular, are there any points where this limit fails to exist? And at the points where the limit does exist, what is the limit equal to?

> No, there are no points where the limit does not exist, and at every point, the limit is equal to $0$. To see this, note that $f(x_0 + h) = c$ and $f(x_0) = c$, so the numerator is always $0$.

Thus, if we define a function 
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h},
$$
then $f'$ is defined for all $x$, and it is continuous everywhere, as required.